# New to photoshop. looking for help/tutorials creating a UI

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design

like the title says, im fairly new to photoshop. Ive learnt a few things within the last few months just playing about by myself and using youtube videos for help. I wanted to learn how to use PS to re design a UI for a game that I play. To give you a vague idea of the level I'm at, I managed to create this as my first attempt:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/srMKc.jpg

I made that from using this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOK9L.jpg
and other various elements that I found online

I was quite pleased with what I managed to do but id like to be able to make my own totally from scratch. I've searched the internet for any kind of help but there doesn't seem to be much out there. youtube helps, but there's a lot of "speed" designs, which are cool to watch them being made but not very helpful in terms of learning. there's a few that go into more detail but the majority of them are not made by English speakers =[

most recently ive been trying to play around with the pen tool - I was afraid of that for a while because I had no idea how to begin with it. but thanks to youtube again, I feel a bit more confident in using it now. my main issue atm is managing to create anything small enough for a game element that actually looks decent (struggling with details being clear enough with them being so small - not sure if I'm doing something wrong when making a new doc or something?)

Any ways.. Just looking for some direction on how to improve and where to learn.

very much appreciated

Comment: You probably shouldnt design ui's in photoshop. It was done in late 1990s and early 2000 but has dropped out of favour because its extremely cumbersome to test.

Comment: the game this is for is from around that time frame any ways so there's no easy way to to test it. nothing fancy like unity. I'm not looking to gain anything from doing this. its just for fun =]

Comment: I think what you're asking is not interface design, but assets creation. Dialogs on your screenshots look like illustrations. So what _exactly_ you're asking about: how to design a layout or how to paint on top of a layout?

Comment: Ah rite sorry, yeah that's my inexperience showing lol. I'd like to know how to make and design the assets. Orbs, menu and header box's, item slots, buttons etc.. 

Comment: In this case you need some courses on digital painting. [Ctrl+Paint](https://www.ctrlpaint.com/library/) has some free and paid in-depth stuff for beginners, generally you may try to search youtube for 'game assets photoshop' — there are a lot of shitty timelapses but there's some nice content also, you just need to spend some time on filtering it out.

Comment: Thanks @kritskiy I'll have a nosey around that site and see what I can find!

Comment: Ahh ok so your trying to skin the UI. Thats not exactly the same as designing a ui and yes that is easy to test since its mostly the same UI. Just copy the files and draw on top.

Comment: Can you recommend any other learning resources for me to take a look at?